# Is there a way to search through content that is fetched from a json file from another view controller?

Tags: swift

So I'm working on a project that fetches data from a server and search through it.

I have 2 different Collection view controllers where one shows data of products from a json file and another which fetches data of stores. I have put my searchbar on the homepage and linked it to the searchbar delegate. I tried using it as search controller and to update results too but it fails so I'm stuck trying to find how to have a separate search controller and search result updating view controller. I've watched many tutorials but none actually covers how to search for content in another view controller(especially collection views). Most just search content in the current vc which is easy. Any idea or help is really appreciated.

```
class FrontPageController: BaseCollectionViewController {

    var sections: [Sections]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.register(FrontPageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "sectionId")
        configureUI()
        fetchFrontPageSections()
    }

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    func configureUI() {

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for product or store"
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .lightGray
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .primaryDark
        showSearchBarButton(shouldShow: true)

        definesPresentationContext = true
```

BaseCollectionViewController

```
class BaseCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var searchActive: Bool = false

    var products: [Products]?
    var filteredProducts = [Products]()

    var stores: [Stores]?
    var filteredstores = [Stores]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red

        collectionView?.register(ProductsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "productId")
        collectionView?.register(StoresCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "storeId")
```

StoreSearchController

```
class StoreSearchController: BaseCollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        fetchStores()
    }
```

ProductSearchController

```
class ProductSearchController: BaseCollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        fetchProducts()
    }
```

So I expect that when I click the search bar in the front-page it should modally present the BaseController class with filtered results of the content in productsearch and storesearch collection view controllers. The front-page has to be the searchbar delegate because that's where i should search from. What class do i make my search controller delegate and what class do i make my searchresultsupdating. Do i need a new vc to handle filtering results? or can base controller do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could simply move that 'data of products from a json file' to a global array, which then can be used anywhere in the project. And then you could filter based on that global array and save it to another local array or another global array(depending on your usage) and show elements from that array on your search.